# How to display constraint using ESQL/C?

Tags: sql, postgresql, embedded-sql

I have to output the constraint in my PostgreSQL using ESQL/C that I have set before directly with SQL. Below is the constraint I need to print out.

```
ALTER TABLE p
ADD CONSTRAINT check_name_of_det 
CHECK ((name = 'Screw' AND n_det = 'P6') OR n_det <>'P6');
```

Comment: What do you want printed out? And when?

Comment: In case  I'm trying to execute sql query to the table with constraint. When I operate this I attain sqlca.sqlcode == -400 therefore I have to print out constraint that this table has.

Comment: What does sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pg_get_constraintdef` function. The argument is the object ID from `pg_constraint`.